# Injection of EntityManager in Hibernate returns null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I am trying to set up a basic Quarkus Hibernate application to persist a simple Film entity to the Sakila test database. I've been following the guide https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm but the injection of an `EntityManager` in my `FilmService` returns `null` no matter what I try. Most parts of the code have been used with no issues in other non-Quarkus Hibernate applications, e.g. the Entity beans `Actor` and `Film`.

Appreciate any advice on how to properly get hold of an `EntityManager`.

**application.properties**

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = mysql
quarkus.datasource.username = root
quarkus.datasource.password = sakila
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
```

It should be noted that I have tested my database config in a separate Hibernate/Panache application to confirm nothing is wrong with the database connection.

**Main.class**

```
package com.example;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FilmService filmService = new FilmService(); 
    
        filmService.createFilm("Sagan om ringen");
    }
}
```

**FilmService.class**

```
package com.example;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped; 
import javax.inject.Inject; 
import javax.persistence.EntityManager; 
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@ApplicationScoped public class FilmService { 

    @Inject EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void createFilm(String giftDescription) {
        Film film = new Film();
        film.setFilmId((short) 12312);
        film.setTitle(giftDescription);
        if (em != null) {
            em.persist(film);
        } else {
            System.out.println("EM is null!!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Film.class**

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.*; 
import java.math.BigDecimal; 
import java.sql.Timestamp; 
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Set;

@Entity 
public class Film {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "film_id", columnDefinition = "SMALLINT UNSIGNED")
    private short filmId;
    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "title", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private String title;
       
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rental_duration", columnDefinition = "YEAR")
    private short rentalDuration;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "language_id", columnDefinition = "SMALLINT UNSIGNED")
    private short languageId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rental_rate", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(4,2)")
    private BigDecimal rentalRate;
    
    @Basic    
    @Column(name = "length", columnDefinition = "SMALL UNSIGNED")
    private Short length;
    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rating", columnDefinition = "enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17')")          
    private String rating;
    
    @Basic    
    @Column(name = "replacement_cost")  
    private BigDecimal replacementCost;
    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "last_update") 
    private Timestamp lastUpdate;
    
    public short getFilmId() {
        return filmId;
    }
    
    public void setFilmId(short filmId) {
        this.filmId = filmId;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    
    public short getLanguageId() {
        return languageId;
    }
    
    public void setLanguageId(short languageId) {
        this.languageId = languageId;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    public short getRentalDuration() {
        return rentalDuration;
    }
    
    public void setRentalDuration(short rentalDuration) {
        this.rentalDuration = rentalDuration;
    }
    
    public String getRating() { return rating; }
    
    public void setRating(String rating) { this.rating = rating; }
    
    public BigDecimal getRentalRate() {
        return rentalRate;
    }
    
    public void setRentalRate(BigDecimal rentalRate) {
        this.rentalRate = rentalRate;
    }
    
    public Short getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    
    public void setLength(Short length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
    
    public BigDecimal getReplacementCost() {
        return replacementCost;
    }
    
    public void setReplacementCost(BigDecimal replacementCost) {
        this.replacementCost = replacementCost;
    }
    public Timestamp getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }
    
    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "film_actor",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "film_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id") }
    )
    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<>();
    
    public void addActor(Actor actor) {
        actors.add(actor);
        actor.getFilms().add(this);
    }
    
    public void removeActor(Actor actor) {
        actors.remove(actor);
        actor.getFilms().remove(this);
    }
    
    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return this.actors; 
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    
        Film film = (Film) o;
    
        if (filmId != film.filmId) return false;
        if (rentalDuration != film.rentalDuration) return false;
        if (title != null ? !title.equals(film.title) : film.title != null) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(film.description) : film.description != null) return false;
        if (rentalRate != null ? !rentalRate.equals(film.rentalRate) : film.rentalRate != null) return false;
        if (length != null ? !length.equals(film.length) : film.length != null) return false;
        if (replacementCost != null ? !replacementCost.equals(film.replacementCost) : film.replacementCost != null)
            return false;
        if (lastUpdate != null ? !lastUpdate.equals(film.lastUpdate) : film.lastUpdate != null) return false;
    
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) filmId;
        result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (int) rentalDuration;
        result = 31 * result + (rentalRate != null ? rentalRate.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (length != null ? length.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (replacementCost != null ? replacementCost.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastUpdate != null ? lastUpdate.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

**Actor.class**

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.*; 
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Objects; 
import java.util.Set;

@Entity 
public class Actor {

    public Actor() {}
    
    public Actor(Integer actorId) {
        this.actorId = actorId;
    }
    
    public Actor(Integer actorId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.actorId = actorId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName; 
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "actor_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "smallint(5)")
    private Integer actorId;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(45)")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(45)")
    private String lastName;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "actors")
    private Set<Film> films = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Integer getActorId() {
        return actorId;
    }
    
    public void setActorId(Integer actorId) {
        this.actorId = actorId;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
    public Set<Film> getFilms() {
        return films;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Actor{" +
                "actorId=" + actorId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    
        Actor actor = (Actor) o;
    
        if (!Objects.equals(actorId, actor.actorId)) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(firstName, actor.firstName)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(lastName, actor.lastName);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = actorId != null ? actorId.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Inject`

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with that either.

Comment: did you include a mysql extension in your quarkus application?
But the answer from @geoand might be helpful. Quarkus need to recognize your main function

Comment: Yes I did. Actually, a combination of using @PersistenceContext and using the correct Quarkus annotations in the main method did the trick. Thanks all!

Comment: @JuliaGustafsson if the answer below worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer so future users will know immediately that it works without having to read through the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
@QuarkusMain
public class GreetingMain implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Inject
    FilmService filmService;

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) {
        filmService.createFilm("Sagan om ringen");    
        return 0;
    } 
}
```